# Не удается изменить элемент List

Tags: c#, list

Привет всем.
Не могу изменить элемент List, вот код:

```
public class Net_FindPoint : MonoBehaviour {
struct SearchUnit{
    public Net_FindPoint sender;
    public int searchedID;
    public int hopCount;

    public float suTime;
    public bool suIsSended;
}
}
List<SearchUnit> su = new List<SearchUnit>();

//for(int i=0; i<su.Count; ++i){
//  su.ToArray()[i].suTime -= Time.deltaTime;
//}
foreach (var v in su) 
    su[v].suTime -= Time.deltaTime;
```

Второе решение нашел тут:
[ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175555/modify-elements-in-a-list-by-index)

Но оно не работает, вот что выдает среда:

```
error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `Net_FindPoint.SearchUnit' expression to type `int'

error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `System.Collections.Generic.List<Net_FindPoint.SearchUnit>.this[int]' has some invalid arguments
```

Comment: Мб так:  v.suTime -= Time.deltaTime;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Решение зависит от того, является ли `Net_FindPoint.SearchUnit` ссылочным типом (классом) или структурой.

Если это класс, скорее всего подойдёт такое:

```
foreach (var v in su) 
    v.suTime -= Time.deltaTime;
```

Если это структура, то вы в цикле получаете каждый раз копию структуры, и вам придётся делать цикл по индексу:

```
for (int i = 0; i < su.Count; ++i)
{
    var tmp = su[i];
    tmp.suTime -= Time.deltaTime;
    su[i] = tmp;
}
```

Простое присвоение `su[i].suTime -= ...` не работает, потому что в этом случае вызывается геттер, который снова-таки возвращает копию значения.

Comment: стоит добавить пару слов. почему для структуры через `for` надо будет

Comment: @Grundy: Дописал, спасибо.

Comment: Сделал, но не работает. error CS1612: Cannot modify a value type return value of `System.Collections.Generic.List<Net_FindPoint.SearchUnit>.this[int]'. Consider storing the value in a temporary variable

Comment: @Alerr: А как определено `suTime`? Это важно.

Comment: Добавил в вопросе. suTime - обычная public float переменная структуры.

Comment: @Alerr: Исправил.

Comment: @Alerr, [немного справки об этой ошибке](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/wydkhw2c.aspx)

Comment: @VladD, а мне кажется, или раньше это работало?

Comment: @Grundy: Хм. Даже и не припомню точно. У меня редко бывают массивы мутабельных структур.

Comment: Эммм, вот оно что) Да, вроде работало раньше...

Comment: У Lista есть метод toArray(). Можете обьяснить его основное назначение? Для чего он?

Comment: @Alerr: Ну, он создаёт массив такого же размера, и копирует туда элементы. Мне за всю жизнь понадобился раза два, не больше. Нужен на случай, если какой-то метод по странной прихоти автора хочет на вход массив, а не `IEnumerable<T>`. В вашем случае не сработало потому, что в массив помещаются копии элементов.

Answer (score 1):

А что тут непонятного? Вы пытаетесь обратиться к элементу списка, использовав не `int` индекс, а некий `Net_FindPoint.SearchUnit`. Вы неправильно итерируетесь через список. Попробуйте:

```
v.suTime -= Time.deltaTime;
```

Просто `for (var x in y)` вызывается для каждого элемента в списке `y`, где `x` - какой-то элемент из списка `y`.

Comment: Да, я пробовал по-всякому. Когда su[i].* = *; пишу, то тоже вылетает ошибка: error CS1612: Cannot modify a value type return value of `System.Collections.Generic.List<Net_FindPoint.SearchUnit>.this[int]'. Consider storing the value in a temporary variable

Answer (score 0):

> deltaTime - Время в секундах, которое потребовалось для завершения
>   последнего кадра (только чтение).

Скорее всего у тебя что-то не так с типами данных самого списка. Как вариант, ты пытаешься присвоить не интовому элементу списка число int.

Так же подозрительно, что ты используешь индекс в списке. У тебя Список массивов?

Для более точного ответа, не помешало бы уточнить вопрос, добавив объявление списка.

Comment: deltaTime - это float. Добавил обьявление списка.