# Разница между вызовом методов класса и структур

Tags: c#, классы, структуры

Имеется такая ситуация

```
struct Point
{
   int x;
   int y;
   public void SetX(int a){ ...  }
   public void SetY(int a){ ...  } 
}
class A
{
   Point cord = new Point(); 
   public Point Cord      
   {
     get { return cord; }  
   }
   public void MethodA(int a)
   {
       cord.SetX(a);   //здесь все ок
   }
}

class B
{
   A myObj = new A();
   public Point Cord      
   {
     get { return cord; }  
   }
   public void MethodB(int a)
   {
       myObj.Cord.SetX(a);   //а здесь не присваивает значение
   }
}
```

В классе А метод отрабатывает верно, а в классе B нет( заходит в метод , где то чему то значение присваивает , но в объекте myObj и в его поле cord типа Point нет)
Интересно чему все таки это значение присваивается и почему с классами работает, а со структурой нет.

Comment: Это не скомпилируется. Вы спрашиваете члены, у которых уровень доступа неявно установлен `private`.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, скорее всего там опечатка и вызов свойства идет `myObj.Cord.SetX(a);`

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, да , опечатался

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что структура это ValueType и копируется полностью.

В результате вызова

```
get { return cord; }
```

Будет **новый** объект структуры, в котором ты и вызываешь метод `SetX`.

Comment: почему новый, у меня же есть поле cord, а это просто его свойство?

Comment: @MikhailZnak, потому что такое поведение структур: когда они передаются в качестве параметров либо возвращаются в качестве результата метода - передается и возвращается полная копия объекта. За исключением `ref` и `out` параметров

Comment: все дошло)  он не ссылку будет возвращать , а значение

Comment: тогда другой вопрос возникает, если какой то способ, не загромождая код лишними методами это скорректировать?

Comment: @MikhailZnak, используй класс вместо структуры, второй вариант - добавь сеттер для поля в который будешь устанавливать новый объект

Comment: Это, кстати, один из классических примеров того, почему мутабельные структуры — зло.

Comment: @MikhailZnak: Чтобы исправить код, делайте так: прочитайте копию структуры, измените её при помощи вызова метода, и запишите на место оригинала назад через setter.

Comment: @MikhailZnak, [связанный вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/584266/186999)